# Display the values of a dataframe (Python), in a frame of a tkinter interface; without giving the possibility to the user to click on it

Tags: pandas, tkinter, tkinter-layout

Good morning,
I'm trying to get the following image (representation of a Pandas dataframe in the frame of a tkinter--> interface without the possibility of user input):  [display tkinter] --->[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlsM1.jpg),
from a dataframe I made using Python Pandas [Python Pandas display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2lF7.jpg)

Could you help me please; I tried lots of things but without success.
You can do this with a dummy dataframe (4 rows x 4 columns). I can take inspiration from your code and apply it.

Thanks in advance.

I'm a beginner and I've tried a lot of beginner stuff without success. Any input would be welcome. THANKS.